# Could Not locate gemfile even though bundler is successfully installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I was able to install this

```
~/workspace $ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.2
1 gem installed
```

However when I put in bundle install, I keep getting

```
Could not locate Gemfile
```

I tried updating and cd to my workspace but I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do you have Gemfile in your workspace? you should move to your workspace and check whether the Gemfile is present and do `bundle install` there.

Comment: if you don't have Gemfile there then do `bundle init`

Answer (score 13):

Do you have `Gemfile` in your workspace directory?

- If "yes", please make sure it is in the correct directory - > `path_to_your_app/Gemfile` and has *no* extensions - >`Gemfile.rb` is incorrect.
- If "no" , please run `bundle init` first and after that `bundle install`.

Comment: "bundle init" helped me